# Can't search for attachments in shared mailbox (office 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

For one user in Office 365, they can't search for attachments in a mailbox they have full permissions on but they can search for attachments in their own mailbox (Outlook 2013).

Other users can search their shared mailboxes for attachments. I see that there is nothing left to index. Why would it be able to search for text in a shared mailbox but can't search for a specific attachment when you enter the filename?

Answer (score 0):

First confirm in OWA you can search as expected (I suspect this will be the case).  This will be a good indication server index is fine, but the client has the problem.

You can rebuild the Outlook search index.

1. Outlook - open back stage
2. Select Options
3. Select Search
4. Select Indexing Options
5. Select Advanced
6. Select Rebuild

In this same Advanced dialog there is a "File type" tab - I would double check that the attachment file types are not deselected in here (I think this is most likely not the case - as it's really only modified by add-ins).

If you continue to have issues - I would also try running with no add-ins and as a last resort create a new profile for the user.